# How to show $V$ is an open subset of $NM$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image]

How to show $V$ is an open subset of $NM$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $U\subset Y$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Comment: We define $f:NM\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x,v)=|v|-\delta (x)$, then $V=f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$. Is this the answer for your hint?

Comment: @Borntobeproud Exactly. And clearly, $f$ is continuous.